# Canvas elements as a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, hyperlink

I have an interactive map of country in my canvas. User can move and zoom it.
This map consists of different regions of that country.

The next thing I want to do is when user hovers specific region of country on map (each region is made by functions: beginPath,moveTo, lineTo, closePath, fill, stroke), this region gets highlighted and then when user clicks on that region, some popup appear.

What is the way of implementing this?

Comment: Are you doing it in OOP?

Comment: It would had been easier. E.g every country would had been an object instantiated from one class where each country would have a property which will have its link.

Comment: Maybe this? http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#hit-regions

Comment: I think you didn't understand a problem. The main problem is how to determine which region of country has been hovered with mouse if any.

Comment: so use event object to get mouse `x` and `y` and then check to which region this `x` and `y` belongs.

Comment: Ok, it's easy to get both coordinates. But is the way to check what region does it belong to?

Comment: to codename, I'd be great if it was true. But  addHitRegion is a new feature and as I checked it's not implemented in Chrome and as Internet says it's not implemented in any other browser.

Comment: hitRegion is a no-go : i even saw a (Chromium) discussion about dropping the feature from the spec. IsPointInPath() is the way to go.

Comment: Check out this USA map using html canvas (with popup information). DougX has written some nice code that seems to fit your needs: http://dougx.net/map/usmap.html

Comment: You have to keep track of each country and choose it based on mouse location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [GameAlchemist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/856501/gamealchemist) and [markE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411591/marke) comments (also thanks to [markE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411591/marke) link http://dougx.net/map/usmap.html)

I've come to solution: each time mousemove event fires, I draw each region. But I neither stroke nor fill it. So after each closePath method I use IsPointInPath() method to check if mouse hovers this region and from that point I can highlight it or do whatever I need.

The key thing there (thanks to https://shifteleven.com/demo/canvas-hit-detection/) that I don't fill and stroke regions - the thing that takes computer resources. I just draw hidden path and check if mouse hovers this path - region. Follow the link above and it provide it with example of up to 100000 planets drawn on canvas. You may notice that it takes some time to draw these planets and how fast it determines which planet is clicked.